# CTRL not working when clicked to perform the code allocated to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

so the code was working but i dont know what happened, so if you click the Left CTRL or the right CTRL the red/yellow should fire a bullet but that's not happening . so i used print to check if the code would append something to the red/yellow_bullet lists but it didnt so is the problem from my side or is it a problem in the code???
please help

Code :

```
import pygame
import os

from pygame import event #opereting system


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500 #this is to make the WINDOW
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Maisa Ahmed") 

DARK_GREEN = (00, 64, 00)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLOOD_RED = (136, 8, 8)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

boarder = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2-5, 0, 10, HEIGHT) 
FPS = 60
SPACESHIP_WIDTH , SPACESHIP_HEIGHT = 55,40
velocity = 5
Bullet_velocity = 7
MAX_BULLETS = 5

YELLOW_HITS = pygame.USEREVENT + 1 
RED_HITS = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

#importing images 

YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png'))

YELLOW_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)), 90)


RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', "spaceship_red.png"))

RED_SPACESHIP = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)),270)




def draw_window(red ,yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets): 
    
    WIN.fill(DARK_GREEN) 
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, boarder)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (red.x, red.y)) 

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLOOD_RED, bullet)

    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)

    pygame.display.update() 


def yellow_movement(keys_pressed, yellow):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - velocity > 0: 
            yellow.x -= velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and yellow.x + velocity + yellow.width < boarder.x:
            yellow.x += velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and yellow.y - velocity > 0:
            yellow.y -= velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and yellow.y + velocity + yellow.height < HEIGHT - 10:
            yellow.y += velocity
def red_movement(keys_pressed, red):
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and red.x - velocity > boarder.x + boarder.width: # left
            red.x -= velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and red.x + velocity + red.width < WIDTH: # right
            red.x += velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and red.y - velocity > 0:# up
            red.y -= velocity
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and red.y + velocity + red.height < HEIGHT - 10:  # down
            red.y += velocity
        

def handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red):
    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        bullet.x += Bullet_velocity

        if red.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(event.Event(RED_HITS))
            yellow_bullets.remove

    for bullet in red_bullets:
        bullet.x -= Bullet_velocity

        if yellow.colliderect(bullet):
            pygame.event.post(event.Event(YELLOW_HITS))
            red_bullets.remove






def main():
    red = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    yellow = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT) # x,y , width , height 

    red_bullets = []
    yellow_bullets = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() # create a clock object which can be used to keep track of time
    run = True
    while run: #event loop
        clock.tick(FPS) #ensures that you will never go above the FPS you set the game on
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #.QUIT to end pygame in the loop
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_LCTRL and len(yellow_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:

                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        yellow.x + yellow.width, yellow.y + yellow.height//2 - 2,10,5) # so it goes from the middle 
                    yellow_bullets.append(bullet)

                if event.type == pygame.K_RCTRL and len(red_bullets) < MAX_BULLETS:

                    bullet = pygame.Rect(
                        red.x, red.y + red.height//2 - 2,10,5) # so it goes from the middle 
                    red_bullets.append(bullet)


        print(red_bullets, yellow_bullets)
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed() # this tells us what keys are being clicked every 1
        yellow_movement(keys_pressed, yellow)
        red_movement(keys_pressed, red)

        handle_bullets(yellow_bullets, red_bullets, yellow, red)



        draw_window(red, yellow, red_bullets, yellow_bullets) #you took the yellow and red to the Drawing functions 

    pygame.quit #.quit to end pygame in general


if __name__ == "__main__": #doesnt matter

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `event.type == pygame.K_LCTRL` to `event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL` and `event.type == pygame.K_RCTRL` to `event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL`